# How to run current open file with 'dotnet run' command in VS CODE?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-code

I have a project in VS Code with multiple .cs files. Executing 'dotnet run' returns an error saying there is more than 1 entry point(main() method).

I am trying to find a way to only run the currently selected/opened file when I execute 'dotnet run' from the terminal. The only solution I found was to hardcode the name of the [Namespace.ClassName] into StartupObject property in the .csproj file.

I need a more abstract approach to tell VS Code that the StartupObject should be Namespace.${fileBasenameNoExtension}

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
  <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  <RootNamespace>C__SQL</RootNamespace>
  <StartupObject>Csharp_SQL.${fileBasenameNoExtension}</StartupObject>
</PropertyGroup>
```

I am trying to implement something similar to the above code

Comment: Why do you have multiple entrypoints in a single program, _at the first place_? There should be only one.

Comment: I am testing small programs and want to avoid having to setup a new dotnet-console for each one.

Comment: Why don't you use a command line argument and choose which method to run? Your approach so far would just keep you struggling.

Comment: I wasn't sure how to implement it via the command line. Use an alias?